# Sharing an object from cone component to another Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to share an object from my first component to the second. I am able to log the 'strVal'(string) defined in the Login Component, in my Home Component but I am unable to log the value of 'abc'(Object) from the Login Component, in the HomeComponent. I am confused why one value from Login Component gets available to Home Component and other does not! The code for Login Component in below

> Login.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';
import { User } from '../contract';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    error = '';
    us: User[];
    abc: any[];
    strVal: string = "Rehan";
    current: any;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.getUs();
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Username and Password Incorrect');
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.model = [];
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            });
    }

    getUs() {
        this.authenticationService.getUsers().subscribe(
            res => this.us = res
        );
    }

    chek() {
        this.abc = this.us.filter(a => a.Login === this.model.username);
        console.log(this.abc);
    }
}
```

> Home.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/index';
import { User } from '../contract';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    providers: [LoginComponent]})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    users: User[];

    constructor(private userService: AuthenticationService, private Log: LoginComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
            res => this.users = res
        );
        console.log(this.Log.strVal);
        console.log(this.Log.abc);
    }
}
```

Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the login component nested inside the home component?

Comment: Have a look and @Input() and @Output(). You dont really want access class properties from another component directly.

Comment: Here is a nice simple article which shows you to pass data to a child componet http://learnangular2.com/inputs/

Comment: Also use @Output() to pass data to a parent http://learnangular2.com/outputs/